# How do you attach an AWS ec2 savings plan to an instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-savings-plans

I purchased an ec2 savings plan for a small ec2. I have a small ec2 currently deployed. I am trying to figure out how to attach this saving plan to the ec2. There isn't any good documentation that explains this. Does it automatically get attached? If so how can I confirm?

Comment: [Once you sign up for a Savings Plan, your compute usage will automatically be charged at the discounted Savings Plans prices](https://aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/faq/)